# Не отображаются регистры в отладчике (Нет данных)

Tags: c, visual-studio, ассемблер

Необходимо написать программу на c++, одна из функций для которой написана на Ассемблере. Ассемблерные процедуры должны вызываться как 
независимо скомпилированные модули. И, когда я делаю это, в отладчике нет информации о регистрах (пишет, что нет данных). В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Информация о регистрах скорее всего отобразится если произойдет остановка на брекпойнте (точке останова).

Answer (score 0):

Возмжно не установлен пакет Tasma.
Возможно у тебя skaa или OLLY, которые с DOS программами не работает.
Может быть TD кривой.